# Send reminder notifications for user's birthday

Tags: swift, parse-platform, notifications

I am creating an app using Swift and Parse as my backend platform. In my application a User can send an invitation to be connected to another user and as soon as they are connected the app should send notifications to remind the user about his friend’s birthday.

In this scenario I have two moments in which the app should send a notification:

1-  When user A sends an invitation to user B, user B should receive a notification

2-  When it’s user’s B birthday, user A should receive a notification and vice versa

I created a Parse object called AppNotification that is responsible for storing information about the notifications the user should receive. So when a user sends an invitation to another user I am adding a line in the AppNotification table, the same happens when it’s a birthday of a friend. Using this I can calculate the number of unread notifications and show it to the user in the UI using the components badge.

My question is more related to the best way to send the birthday notification. What I am considering is:

1-  When user A sends and invitation to user B I have to send a push notification to user B.

2-  As soon as the users are connected I can schedule local notifications to remind them about the birthday. This solution would use Local Notifications instead of Push Notifications.

3-  Or create a Job in Parse that will be executed every day and will read all the users whose birthday is today and send a push notification to his friends. This solution would use Push notifications and I would not need to worry about scheduling local notifications.

Between the points 2 and 3 which one is the best solution? Is there any other approach I could use?  When should I consider using Local Notifications other than Remote Notifications?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding points 2 and 3: there are pros and cons for both options: Having the reminders as local notifications is basically what your local calendar app does, i.e. you don't need a connection the Internet / Parse. However: what happens if one party (A) decides that she no longer wants to be a "friend" (of B)? Should notifications still be sent? If not, you could easily delete the scheduled notification on the server. This would also ensure that the other party (B) wouldn't receive notifications of a former friend (A) if she didn't open the app in the meantime and synced the list of friends.

There are of course more pros and cons, so it is really a matter of your preference and possibly other constraints (e.g. should an active internet connection be necessity?).

Comment: Thank you for your response. When you say "Should notifications still be sent? If not, you could easily delete the scheduled notification on the server" what do you mean exactly? If we have a local notification scheduled in user's B device to send a reminder of user's A birthday and then user A removes user B as friend, I think we need to remove the local notification from user's B device right ? One way of doing that would be sending a silent notification from Parse to user B when the friendship is removed and then when user B can cancel the local notification.

Comment: True, or you could cancel it when user B opens the app the next time (sync). My intention was to highlight that there is no "this is the one and only way to handle things" approach.